# Is there anything as good as TOAD for Postgres (Windows)?

Tags: database, postgresql, toad

I'm just looking for a management tool like TOAD for Postgres.  Anyone used a good one?

Edit - I work mostly within the data itself and the database already has a mature model/design.  I use the edit windows the most (well, in TOAD for Oracle anyway.)

As far as I know, Toad only exists naturally for: Oracle, MS SQL, DB2 and MySQL...

--JS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if TOAD for specific DB versions is any different than TOAD for Data Modeler, but   it appears that [TOAD Data Modeler](http://www.toadsoft.com/toaddm/toad_data_modeler.htm) supports PostgreSQL, along with a few others.

If you're looking for something like SQL Server Management Studio, but for Postgres, how about [EMS SQL Manager](http://sqlmanager.net/products/postgresql/manager) or [Lightning Admin](http://www.lightningadmin.com/)?

Comment: Check out my edit :-)  ... the design is already in place, I want to maintain views, data, create edits and so-forth, which, as far as I know, the data modeler doesn't really support directly?  I could be wrong.

Comment: Edited my answer to add a few other options, based on edit to original question.

Comment: Ended up with EMS SQL Manager - thanks for the nudge.

Comment: Quest doesn't have a tool.  I have been asking them for one for EnterpriseDB and Postgres.  They appear to have never heard of Postgres judging by the responses I have received.  EMS SQL manager free edition is very good, Pro is even better.

Answer (score 11):

Doesn't TOAD exist for several plattforms?

I'm using pgAdmin III which fills my needs so far.

http://www.pgadmin.org/

Answer (score 10):

See the wiki: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 3):

[TOra](http://torasql.com/about) has some nice features and is supposed to be a lot like TOAD.  Also, it is completely GPL so you can change the code yourself.

BTW:  Toad is not OpenSource and is now only trialware (must re-install every 120 days).  TOra is OpenSource so you don't have those issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Navicat](http://pgsql.navicat.com/) fairly extensively and successfully but only on a Mac. It has a Windows implementation that is, as far as I know, more feature rich than the Mac implementation.

I've had the odd data typing issue with it but, if you are not doing data modelling, that may not be an issue for you

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not need to edit the database design, I suggest [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/). It is Java application. You can use GUI mode (which I prefer to) and console mode (if you like psql-like command console).
I use this app much more than pgAdmin III or pgAdmin 4 because it helps me to ease monitoring the database activity, deploying new version of DB app, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Navicat for PostgreSQL is working really well for me natively.
I set up phppgAdmin for the teams general use and it has been quite valuea
ble